# create an insert trigger 

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, triggers

How can I write a trigger in SQL Server that will help me to insert values into a table when some data is inserted into another table? And I also want to use the inserted data in the second table to insert the first table.

There is Table A and Table B,

when a row is inserted into Table B(TBLP1ISLEM)

I want to insert several cells from this insertion,

into Table A(TBLP1DOVIZKURU).

Table B, inserted

Trigger help => Table A, inserted

Thank you.

code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Deneme] 
   ON  [dbo].[TBLP1ISLEM] 
   FOR INSERT
AS 
IF(SELECT ID FROM inserted)>0
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO TBLP1DOVIZKURU(ISLEM_ID,DOVIZBIRIM,KUR) 
    SELECT ID, PARABIRIMI, KUR FROM inserted


END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a trigger on Table B for insert. It will allow you to capture the inserted data and do whatever you want with it. You can use the inserted data, you can query another table ... etc ...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_Insert_TableB
ON TableB
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Select * FROM Inserted //This will give you the inserted data
End
```

Comment: thanks, I tried but it did not work, something else maybe wrong with tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
ON  [TableB]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TableA (tA_field1,tA_field2,tA_other_fields)  SELECT tB_field1,tB_field2,tB_other_fields FROM Inserted

END
```

Comment: I wrote a code exactly like that but it did not work, I wonder why

Comment: You get any specific error? Mayby you have some other triggers on Table A that disallow data insert ie PK,FK, constraints, NULLS or other triggers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SYSTEM@valeh> create table emp_list (id number, name varchar2(20));
 SYSTEM@valeh> insert into emp_list values (1,'Valeh');
 SYSTEM@valeh> create table emp_age (age_id number, emp_id number, emp_age number);
 SYSTEM@valeh> create view emp_view as select * from emp_list el,emp_age age where el.id=age.emp_id;


create or replace trigger view_trigger
 instead of insert on emp_view
 referencing new as new old as old
 declare
 v_id VARCHAR(20);
 begin
 if :new.id is not null then
 insert into emp_list (id,name) values (:new.id,:new.name);
 insert into emp_age (age_id,emp_id,emp_age) values (:new.age_id,:new.emp_id,:new.emp_age)
 returning :new.id into v_id;
 else
 raise_application_error (-20999, 'Cannot create employee without name');
 end if;
 end;


SYSTEM@valeh> insert into emp_view values (2,'taleh',2,2,20);

SYSTEM@valeh> select * from emp_view;
```